# Why doesn't a Boolean have to point to an object

Tags: objective-c

When implementing a getter or setter for an NSString it appears as

```
-(NSString *)nameOfSomething
```

however when you get or set a Boolean you don't us an asterisks to point to something

```
-(BOOL)nameOfSomething
```

I was wondering why you have to do this? Shouldn't the asterisks still be needed in order to point? Is there a certain reason a Boolean doesn't need one?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a good idea to learn C before trying to program iOS, because you're going to be using Objective-C, and Objective-C is C. There is a difference between a plain data type and a pointer. The asterisk has to do with pointers. (Objective-C "object" types are all pointers, but C has other types.)

The most important aspects of C needed for iOS programming are discussed here:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch01.html

As that chapter explains, a BOOL is like an NSInteger - it's just a number, not an object.

Comment: I object *Objective-C is C*, **IT is superset of C**

Comment: But NSInteger is an object (A class, actually)

Comment: @LayGonzález No! See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Of course, but it's a kind of shorthand. It is meant to impress upon the student that everything that's true of C is true of Objective-C, so knowing C is kind of important. :) Many beginners don't realize this, and they think they can program iOS without knowing any C. That can be a big mistake.

Comment: @matt: That's good to teach beginners, but this statement may create confusion to few, isn't it. You should make it clear. :)

Comment: @LayGonzález: Not everything beginning with `NS` is a class.

Answer (score 1):

It is a primitive type, just like an int.
In theory, it could be an object, but it is so a very simple concept that makes it of almost no use.

Consider this analogies. (Left for primitive types, right for classes)

```
int  : Integer    (Integer from java)
BOOL :  ---
 --- : NSString
```

and so on.

If you really require an object, make a wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

`BOOL` are just `signed char`, you don not take its address/reference.

**You directly assign to it.**

If you see its definition which is as :

```
typedef signed char     BOOL; 
// BOOL is explicitly signed so @encode(BOOL) == "c" rather than "C" 
// even if -funsigned-char is used.

#if __has_feature(objc_bool)
#define YES             __objc_yes
#define NO              __objc_no
#else
#define YES             ((BOOL)1)
#define NO              ((BOOL)0)
#endif
```

You use to see its value by `%d` not `%@`.